# GHCi error - "Not in scope: `isUpper'"

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm learning haskell and I'm trying to write some simple functions. Everything worked well until I've used function `isUpper`. I'm unable to compile the project because of this error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( C:\Users\...\src\Main.hs, interpreted )
C:\Users\...\src\Main.hs:147:25:
    Not in scope: `isUpper'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude>
```

My code:

```
module Main where
main::IO()
main = undefined
stringIsUpper [] = True
stringIsUpper (x:ys) = (isUpper x) && (stringIsUpper(ys))
```

The goal of this code should be just to check if the inserted string consists of the uppercase letters.
I'm using EclipseFP for development
Thank you for your help

Comment: `isUpper` is a function in `Data.Char`, you have to import it first

Comment: When in doubt, [hoogle it](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=isUpper).

Comment: Thank You @bheklilr. It works. I just thought that I don't have to write imports and also I didn't know, where to place that imports.
Problem is solved

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to `import` [`Data.Char`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.1.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html) to get `isUpper`.